# SELECT and then update in the same column

Tags: sql

I have this in my DB:

```
| id           | time        | time-left   |
| 1            | 242363246   | 1           |
| 2            | 215625252   | 1           |
| 3            | 147852369   | 1           |
| 4            | 951753456   | 1           |
```

How can I insert into `time-left` the same as in `time` but with 111 more? Here is how I want it to become:

```
| id           | time        | time-left   |
| 1            | 242363246   | 242363357   |
| 2            | 215625252   | 215625363   |
| 3            | 147852369   | 147852480   |
| 4            | 951753456   | 951753567   |
```

Comment: What RDBMS engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `time` is an integer or a char type that can be incremented (with implicit conversion):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET "time-left" = time + 111;
```

If `time`can't be incremented this way you have to cast/convert it to an integer type first.

Depending on what DBMS you are using the way to use quoted identifiers for invalid names (like `time-left`in this case) might be something else like using brackets: `[time-left]` (SQL Server) or using backticks: `` `time-left` `` (MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

```
update myTable set "time-left" = time + 111;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update MyTable
set time-left = time + 111
```